# Javascript for looping over array argument

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am trying to loop over an array argument and return the first n elements of the passed array without using standard javascript functions such as slice, concat, push, pop etc...

```
var n = 0;
var anyArray = Array;
var SR = {};
SR.first = function(anyArray,n){
var isArray = (Object.prototype.toString.apply(anyArray) === '[object Array]');
var specification = (typeof n === "number");
if(isArray && specification){
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                return Array(anyArray[i]); 
            }
        }
    else if (isArray || !specification){
        return anyArray[0];
    }
}
```

I do not want to build the return array "anyArray" by using +=. So, how would I proceed to have it return some thing like this [1,2,3,4] when "SR.first([1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 4);" is called?

Comment: Why are you doing this? What's wrong with `your_array.slice(0, 2)`?

Comment: I must say, my curiosity is piqued as well. Why would you not want to use the native functions built into Javascript? They're likely to be far more optimized than manual methods, being, as it were, closer to the source (the javascript engine being usually quite tuned for its companion html browser engine...).

Comment: You can use `filter`: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].filter(function(i) { return i <= 2; });`

Comment: @Blender: If your `i` is meant to be the array index, it should be the second argument.

Comment: Its a project where I gain practice with loops. The purpose was not to have some two line concise code.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newArr = Array.apply(null, anyArray); // new Array using original content

newArr.length = n; // truncate the length of the new Array

return newArr;     // return it
```

One small edge case will be when `anyArray` has only one member, which is a number. You'll need to guard against that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would not want to use `Array` operations like `push` and `slice`, but this would work:

```
if ( isArray && specification ) {
  var result = [];
  for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    result[i] = anyArray[i]; 
  }
  return result;
}
else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you really don't want to use native javascript functions, you can assign each element to your return array one by one.

```
var returnArray = [];

if(isArray && specification) {
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        returnArray[i] = anyArray[i];
    }
}

return returnArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SR.first = function(anyArray,n){ 

  var newArray = [];
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
      newArray[newArray.length] = anyArray[i]; 
  }
  return newArray;

}
```

Comment: newArray[i] = anyArray[i]; // not newArray.length!

Comment: You can do like i do, without problems. It's the same, on my way, I add one item at time in `newArray`

Answer (score 0):

First of all - global variable it's really bad practice! You don't need declare anyArray and n, becouse its a function arguments, and its declared on function call.
Second problem - that you can put number of elements bigger than array length - you must check this situation.

```
var SR = {};
SR.first = function(anyArray,n){
    var isArray = (anyArray instanceof Array),
        specification = (typeof n === 'number'),
        tmp = new Array;
    console.log(isArray, specification);
    if(isArray && specification){
        for(i = 0, l = anyArray.length; i < n && i < l; i++){
            tmp[i] = anyArray[i];
        }
        return tmp;
    } else if (isArray || !specification){
        return anyArray[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Silver_Clash, this is exactly what I wanted and will learn from.